# Unable to authenticate your payment method in stripe 3d secure

Tags: stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I am using flutter_stripe in fluter and when I am doing transaction and I am confirming the payment with the the below method

`Stripe.instance.confirmPayment(paymentIntentClientSecret: 'my_client_seceret_key')`

when.i am trying with visa and master card I am facing error like unable to authenticate and when I am trying with American Express card its working fine with it.

cant decide what's the issue with stripe support

Comment: You need to be more clear. What error message did you get, and how does it look like in your Stripe Dashboard (https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs)

Comment: I am getting error after complete 3dSecure authentication like : "Unabled to authenticate" and also check my attached screenshot of stripe dashboard: https://rb.gy/37s6im

Comment: @AalokPrajapati "Payment declined by the issuing bank" is the issue here. Are you implementing this in test mode, or with real cards? If it's in test mode, which card from https://stripe.com/docs/testing are you using?

Comment: I have used test cards for test mode and real card for the live mode but I am facing this issue only in live mode

Comment: @Aalok could you solved the problem? I'm get Authentication error in Google Pay.

Comment: no i am still facing issue with that for solution i have used old payment api which they are provide before payment intent

Answer (score -1):

**Stripe Payment gateway issue**

Stripe.instance.confirmPayment(paymentIntentClientSecret: 'my_client_seceret_key')

**please follow the steps**

- Check API Key and Version:
- Enable Payment Methods:
- Check Test Card Numbers:
- Inspect Error Messages:
- Check Webhooks:
- Verify Integration Code:
- Review Stripe Dashboard Logs:
- Contact Stripe Support:

Comment: I have followed this all steps but still facing this issue in iOS device only